# How to implement airplay for mac application to change sound output source while streaming?

Tags: macos, streaming, airplay, audiostreamer

I am new to mac development,currently I am working an app that streams video and audio files hosted on the web.How can I implement airplay feature to change the sound output source ? I am using JKAudioManager to get all the airplay devices and AudioStreamer to stream the files.

How can I switch between different devices using these two api's ? Is there any other way to do this also?